# sorting lua tables with a table of boolean values

Tags: sorting, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I've searched high and low and have attempted to accomplish this in different stages. 
I'm trying to sort a couple of tables that based on another table values. I've tried to sort these tables by seeding a k, v where v is a boolean.

Here's what I've got so far.. And thank you in advance for any help.

```
function byInstallsField(x,y) 
  -- cant seem to make sens out of the sorting 
  if x.installed then return true
  elseif y.installed == false then return false
  end
end

-- var is the index passed into the function
-- pRect:new is a custom lib for rect' drawing  

playerRect[ var ] = pRect:new(_W  + dimesion_for_rect * var, 0, 
                              dimesion_for_rect, 
                              dimesion_for_rect, 
                              3 ) -- _x, _y , _hieght, _width, round 

playerRect.installed = inst;
table.sort( playerRect, byInstallsField )

downloadedImage[ var ] = fb_friends:new(var, imageOnFile, 
                                        playerRect[ var ].x, 
                                        playerRect[ var ].y,
                                        0.25, 0.25, 0, dimesion_for_rect - 5)
downloadedImage[ var ].id = var
downloadedImage.installed = inst 
table.sort( downloadedImage, byInstallsField )
```

The outcome that I wish would to have the playerRect & the downloadedImage tables to sorted so that the installed that = true would lead the arrays..

> player 1.installed = true , player 2.installed = true , player 3.installed = false

Comment: Clarify what `playerRect.installed = inst` is meant to do. It looks like you have a table of tables but do each of those subtables have an `installed` field? `playerRect.installed` plays no role in the sorting. The subtables is what's being compared in your comparision function -- it won't even return a value if the 2 subtables are missing the `installed` field.

Comment: Even if both arguments to `byInstallsField` have values for `installed`, it's still possible for the function to not return a value (`x.installed` false and `y.installed` true). Your function always has to return true or false. Another way to think about it is that it's not enough to say all the items with `installed` true come before all the items with `installed` false---you need to design an algorithm so that for **every** pair of items, one of them is sorted before the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison function given to `table.sort` must satisfy the *strict ordering* relation. In particular, given `a` and `b` if `byInstall(a, b)` is true then `byInstall(b, a)` ***must*** return false.

Here's a simple example:

```
local player = {
  {"alice", installed = false},
  {"bob", installed = true},
  {"carol", installed = true},
  {"dave", installed = true},
  {"matthew", installed = false},
  {"steve", installed = true},
}

function byInstall(first, second)
  return first.installed and not second.installed
end

table.sort(player, byInstall)
```

After the sort, subtables with `installed = true` will be grouped together. The table `player` will look like:

```
{
  {
    "steve",
    installed = true
  },
  {
    "dave",
    installed = true
  },
  {
    "carol",
    installed = true
  },
  {
    "bob",
    installed = true
  },
  {
    "matthew",
    installed = false
  },
  {
    "alice",
    installed = false
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that's exactly the push i needed thank you for your help. I was completely suck and that was the push i needed..